# Caller drops the call before client answers

Tags: twilio

I'm using the twilio javascript library on my website. I'm trying to figure out when a caller calls my twilio number, what happens if the caller drops the call before the client picks it up from the website. It seems to me the callback set with

```
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {});
```

isn't called for this event.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
Twilio.Device.cancel(function (conn) {});
```

is triggered for this event.